# 'MethodName' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, native

So I am working on implementing some C++/cli and C# interop by using a wrapper class for my native C++ code.

I can't seem to work past the error `'GetSharedData' is not supported by the language`. I've scoured the web for solutions and tried all of the suggestions with no luck.

My code looks like:

```
// c++/cli wrapper code
//
// this wraps an abstract native c++ class
public ref IHamWrapper
{
public:
    // default constructor
    IHamWrapper(){}
    // copy constructor
    IHamWrapper(const IHamWrapper%) {}
    // overloaded ()
    IHamWrapper operator () (NativeCode::INativeClass* data)
    {
        IHamWrapper ham;
        ham.hamData = data;
        return ham;
    }
    bool MethodA(){ wrappedObj->MethodA(); }
    bool MethodB(){ wrappedObj->MethodB(); }
    // etc...
internal:
    IHamWrapper(NativeCode::INativeClass* data)
    {
        wrappedObj = data;
    }
    NativeCode::INativeClass* wrappedObj;
};

public ref class StaticHamCalls
{
public:
    static IHamWrapper% GetSharedData(int param1, int param2)
    {
        return ham(NativeCode::GetSharedData(param1, param2));
    }
private:
    static IHamWrapper ham;
}
```

And this is how I am trying to call it in C#

```
// C# code
public void testFunction()
{
    Int32 param1 = 5;
    Int32 param2 = 10;
    StaticHamCalls.GetSharedData(param1, param2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `^` (handle to object) because C# does not support `%` (tracking reference).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked perfectly when I changed from tracking reference to handle.